# Where new databases are saved in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

The default database which is GratefulDeadConcerts, resides in the .\databases\GratefulDeadConcerts directory.

Ok, but when I create a new database, where does it go? Why new databases also not created in .\databases ?

This is how I create a new database:

[image: This is how I create a new database]

As you can see I have 3 databases but two database directories:

[image: As you can see I have 3 databases but two database directories]:

Comment: How do you create new databases?

Comment: In browser, localhost:2480. I click new DB, then in the form, I fill database name, enter root password and click Create Database. It is shown in upper-right corner.

Comment: Then they should be created in `$ODB_HOME/databases/`

Comment: Ok. I just figured out why it's not shown in $ODB_HOME/databases/. Unless you create some records, the database folder will be empty. No matter how many classes you create, there won't be any database folder. So, why I need to add some records? Where classes are stored?

Comment: No. The database folder is created right after you click on `Create database` button.

Comment: Then how come I see 3 databases in the GUI but just 2 of them in the databases directory? Check the last screenshot from the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75512/discussion-between-ramazan-polat-and-vitorenesduarte).